# can't loop more than once - for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

the task here is :

A. match_ends
Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
and last chars of the string are the same.
Note: python does not have a ++ operator, but += works.

```
def match_ends(words):
    for i in words:
        if (len(i) >= 2) & (i[0] == i[-1]):
            return [i]


print(match_ends(['aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb']))
```

and the output is :

['aba']

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Return exit the function and the for loop the first time it is hit. Replace return by yield and you will have a generator doing what you want.

Comment: You should use `word` instead of `i`.

Comment: You mean `and`, not `&`. And you're supposed to count matches and return the count, not just return `[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (len(i) >= 2) & (i[0] == i[-1]):
     return [i]
```

You return when your if condition is true, and this will stop your function.

You should then save your data in a variable if you want to get all the occurence of it as `res.append(i)` (save i in the list res)

Then return it outside when you have iterate through all your list.

```
def match_ends(words):
    for i in words:
        if (len(i) >= 2) & (i[0] == i[-1]):
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that returns the first and it doesn't keep going

the return keyword stops the function, so you have to store it in an array-like to return it

here is the code optimized:

```
def match_ends(*words):
    result = []
    for i in list(words):
        if len(i) >= 2 and i[0] == i[-1]:
            result.append([i])
    return result


print(match_ends('aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your first item matches your if conditions and as you are using return, your code exits with the result as the first item. I am not sure what you want to do with this function.